# dismissing a popOver

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview, uipopover

in my app i have a Form sheet view which has a two textfields. one of the textfields when tapped a popover with a picker appears. now when the user finishes from the popover, most of the users, tap on the background to dismiss it. even if i place a Done button in the popover, the user reluctantly taps the background. so when i'm tapping the background, the popover disappears. but when i want to edit the other textfield, i have to tap it twice in order to enter the edit mode. it's like when the popover is being presented, there is a layer beneath it and when it disappears the layer stays until i tap the second time to let it go. anybody familiar with this?

Comment: less words, more code please

Comment: What did you just say??

Answer (score 0):

You could create a transparent UIButton on the background when the picker comes up so that when the user taps on the background, you can specify exactly what is to happen.

Comment: i tried making the popover background a UIControl subclass  and use an IBAction method to to fire up when the background is pressed. however, when i tap the background, the method isn't called as if the background doesn't belong to the viewController class of the popover. btw i'm using a segue popover.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you block the background to force the user to dismiss via the popover window

IN the view controller that presents the popover...

```
//when the popover is presented
   UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
   popOver.passthroughViews = @[view];
   [self.view addSubview:view];

  //when the popover is dismissed
   [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
```

(this asumes that the viewController's `self.view` is the background who's touches you want to block)

Similarly, you could implement a view-covering button, with a selector in the viewController:

```
  UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
   popOver.passthroughViews = @[button];
   [self.view addSubview:view];
```

I think that is what you already tried? The missing ingredient would be `passthroughViews`. By default background interaction is *blocked*, aside from the dismissing of the popover (which is why you have that 'invisible layer' impression) - `passthroughviews` allows you to selectively enable those interactions.

Comment: Okay thanks! Btw I'm displaying the popover by a segue and actually there is a pass through option in the inspector of the segue.